# Drawing a Box from Coordinates Using Plotly & Numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plotly

I'm attempting to get started using numpy & plotly, but ... almost no experience with these libraries. Having some difficulty getting started. Any help figuring out the things I need to understand to get the following code working would be greatly appreciated ...

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px



# 2D Coordinates - just trying to figure out the basics
coordinates = np.array([
    [1, 1],
    [2, 2]
  ])

print("Size:       %i" % coordinates.size)
print("Dimensions: %i" % coordinates.ndim)
print("Shape:      %s" % str(coordinates.shape))

# the numpy coordinate array is in the wrong format ... is it possible to pass
# in the numpy array directly, or do i need to reformat the data?
# (from: https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/)
# fig = px.scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16])
# fig.show()


# 3D Coordinates - what I'm really trying to do ...
coordinates = np.array([
    [443, 2, -53],
    [393, 2, -53],
    [444, 2, -70],
    [393, 2, -70]
  ])

print("Size:       %i" % coordinates.size)
print("Dimensions: %i" % coordinates.ndim)
print("Shape:      %s" % str(coordinates.shape))
```

Answer (score 1):

From what you have described it is **slicing** that's required.

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
c = np.array([
    [443, 2, -53],
    [393, 2, -53],
    [444, 2, -70],
    [393, 2, -70]
  ])

px.scatter_3d(x=c[:,0], y=c[:,1], z=c[:,2])
```

[image]